# xslt conversion fraction

Tags: xslt

I have a file with a `<fraction d="2" n="1">` tag. I need to convert it to `&frac12;` I tried doing it with this:

```
<xsl:template match="fraction">
  <xsl:text>&frac</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@n"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="@d"/>
  <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

but I get an error- possibly due to referencing &frac

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work for me (xslt 1.0):

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;frac</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="@n"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="@d"/>
  <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

**There is no need for DOE** (and **[its use isn't just bad taste](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N2215.html)**!):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <my:fractions>
  <frac14>&#188;</frac14>
  <frac12>&#189;</frac12>
  <frac34>&#190;</frac34>
  <frac18>&#8539;</frac18>
  <frac38>&#8540;</frac38>
  <frac58>&#8541;</frac58>
  <frac78>&#8542;</frac78>
 </my:fractions>

 <xsl:variable name="vFracs" select="document('')/*/my:fractions/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="fraction">
     <xsl:value-of select="$vFracs[name()= concat('frac', current()/@n, current()/@d)]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<fraction d="2" n="1"/>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
½
```